# How can I have single facebook sign in across two android apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-android-sdk

I have two android apps with two different package names. I want to use FB sign in to let the user sign into my app. How can I do it such that the user just have to sign in on one app and the SDK on other app automatically detect the sign in.

And how to do similar thing on iPhone in future?

Comment: On your Facebook Application settings you're not allowed to set multiple package names for Android. This would be one issue. On iOS, what I would try doing is try and sharing the Access Token between apps? I found a tutorial here: http://enharmonichq.com/sharing-data-locally-between-ios-apps/

Comment: Are they the same app (like a free and premium version), or are they different apps (like Candy Crush and Farmville)?

Comment: I am facing the same problem , i want to use it on free and premium @MingLi do you know any solution for it ?